# How do I connect to an SMB share requiring a user name and password?

Tags: 12.04, samba, smb

I have a samba share on my LAN that requires a username and password to obtain write access (otherwise it defaults to read-only).

I can't figure out where in the Unity desktop I can connect to the share and be prompted for my login credentials.  I can mount the drive, of course, but then I'm browsing as a guest (read-only).

What gives?

Comment: Unity doesn't really have anything to do with file sharng. Try File->Connect to Server in the Nautilus file browser.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In top menu of the file browser click Go>Location and enter `smb://user@host/sharename`.
You will then be prompted to enter a password.

Comment: what is 'sharename'

Comment: @AdamJohns The share name is whatever the network share is named on that Samba share server...

Comment: is there a command line equivalent?

Comment: Nuzzolilo, search for `smbclient`

Comment: what if we use email address as username?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Guest account without a password:

```
smb://Guest:@server_name
```

If you have a user account with a password:

```
smb://user_name:password@server_name
```

If you have a user account but only want to be prompted for the password:

```
smb://user_name:*@server_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 15.04, you can open the file server, and use the connect to the server option on the bottom left

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)