# How to connect to smb://...?

Tags: filesystem, files, file-sharing, smb

I would like to connect from Ubuntu 14.04 to a file server (e.g., "smb://files.myuni.ca"). I opened Files and then chose "Connect to Server". A minimalistic menu pops up. If I provide the server address and hit "Connect", the window disappears, but nothing seems to happen. How can I get a connection?

I also tried the idea on [How do I connect to an SMB share requiring a user name and password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-smb-share-requiring-a-user-name-and-password) but that did not work either.

Comment: You entered wrong address. If you enter wrong address it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @FilipSohajek: Why are our comments deleted (?) Your idea how to use the terminal was useful!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I presume Samba is installed?

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Open Nautilus, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>. In the address bar type `smb://location.of.folder`

When you use connect to server, is the new mounted now listed on the left hand side of Nautilus as a mounted drive ?

Comment: I'm not sure where my comment above disappeared, but well... Yes, Samba is installed. Pressing ctrl+l and putting in the address leaves me with a blank window.... for a *while*. Out of a sudden, the drive now appear... thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I had to use the address `smb://MyServer/MySharedDirectory`