# I can login to my server through the terminal, but can't get in through Mac network

Tags: 18.04

I can login to my ubuntu 18.04 server with my credentials as usual, but if I try to login through `cmd + k` on my mac and use the same login credentials, it doesn't allow me to login. Are there different credentials for this? do I have to create new ones?

**UPDATE**

I have my username `JAKE` and have my password `myPassword` which when I am on the server or use ssh, I can provide JAKE and myPassword to login. When on my mac, and I want to connect to a server, I put in smb://192.168.11.32/sambashare (the folder to connect to) and then it gives me the login screen, but `JAKE` and `myPassword` aren't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to an SMB share requiring a user name and password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-smb-share-requiring-a-user-name-and-password)

Comment: I think your missing the `smb://user@host_ip/sambashare` format try that and lets see!

Comment: Another thing make sure you did set the samba user's password too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have configured this already, but Samba does not use the system password for your user.

You need to set one with **sudo smbpasswd -a username**

More information on configuring samba on Ubuntu can be found here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share

Comment: Thanks Justus95 that worked for me just ssh in and set smb password even use same thing using justus95 line and then disconnect drive reconnect and sign in as you do on server and all good