# Permission denied, 20.04 to 20.04 unable to share

Tags: permissions, 20.04, samba

I have 2 machines with 20.04. On `machine A`, I have Samba set up and then used `Local Network Share` on a folder, with a few subfolders. The shared folder is visible under `Network` in `machine B`. When I click on it, it asks 3 values 1. user name 2. domain ( which is already filled as WORKGROUP ) 3. Password. I tried using various combinations. ie, an user ID and password from `machine A` and a user ID and password from `machine B` ( both admins ). In both cases, there is an error message like " Permission Denied ".

To make things easier, I tried allowing `Guest Access`. When tried to access the shared folder from `machine B` , it gives the same " Permission Denied " error. To be sure, I logged out from both machines and tried to access the shared folder without success. Any help will be great.

Comment: I think one of the most efficent way to share files between two *nix systems is to use `sftp`. That aside, have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-smb-share-requiring-a-user-name-and-password)?

Answer (score 3):

> When I click on it, it asks 3 values 1. user name 2. domain ( which is
> already filled as WORKGROUP ) 3. Password. I tried using various
> combinations. ie, an user ID and password from machine A

Two different passwords in Linux. There is the local machine A username and password. Then there is the samba password for that local user. You need to add the local user to the samba password database. For example to add myself:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a morbius
```

THe issue with guest access is something else. We need to see more information. If you really want guest access please edit your original post and add the output of the following commands:

```
testparm -s

net usershare info --long
```

Comment: I have samba served from 16.04, with 1 samba user. All my windows machine connect with this same user. On Ubuntu 20 workstation, trying to connect with this user gives permission denied (from ngome file browser add network share). I've also tried mounting via cifs, same error. Thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following.

- right click the drive in question.
- go to properties
- go to security
- add 'Everyone' to the list of 'Group or names' and give it full control
- apply, ok, ok,

For good measure I also clicked the 'Advanced' button in the Security tab and changed the ownership of the disk from 'System' to myself.